# How to Fix Dark File Names in High Contrast Theme VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: What it looks like]

How come some of the text is not well seen?

This never happened previously and I searched for settings in the preferences menu, but am currently at a loss as to what the root issue is.

Any suggestion/help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug in VS Code, I ended up just restarting the application and the issue was fixed. Strange to say to least...

**Edit:**

This was caused by `git decorations` which changed the color of the text name depending on the file status (modified, added, staged, etc.).

Since I find this distracting rather than helpful, I simply did `file > preferences > settings > searched "git decorations" > unchecked "Git > Decorations: Enabled"`

Answer (score 2):

You can customize your color scheme in the JSON format of VS Code Settings so that the text in the side bar can be seen more easily.

First, open Command Palette via `Ctrl + Shift + P` and type `Preferences: Open Settings (JSON)`. Press enter such that the VS Code Settings JSON file would open.

Next, add the following code into the JSON file:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "[your_color_scheme_name_here]": {
        "sideBar.foreground": "#ffffff",
    }
}
```

Replace the `your_color_scheme_name_here` with the name of your color scheme. For example, if my color scheme is called `Monokai Pro`, then I type `"[Monokai Pro]": {` in the second line of the code snippet. Next, replace the `#ffffff` color code with a color you wish to have. Save the JSON file and you should be able to see the changes immediately at the side bar.

You can learn more about what other color customizations you can make in the side bar in the [official documentation here](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#side-bar).